# Access Portal of upstream routers

Tags: networking, router, static-routes

Following is the schematic of my office network:
[image]

I am accessing all the routers from my PC (IP: 10.198.158.148 as shown in the figure). IP: 10.198.158.100 takes me to edgerouters portal. Edgerouter is in [load balancing mode](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/205145990-EdgeRouter-WAN-Load-Balancing); where the expensive cable network will be used if the primary wireless network fails. From edgerouter's console, I am able to see that eth0 is assigned IP: 192.168.200.200, and cable company IP: 25.178.199.200. If I try to access both these addresses from my PC, I am taken to edgerouter's (IP: 10.198.158.1) portal.

In the eth0 of my edgerouter I have connected a wireless modem via [TPLink router](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/tl-wr902ac/).

I wanted to access the TPLink router's portal from my PC (IP: 10.198.158.148 as shown in the figure) for easy maintenance. How do I do that?

Comment: Configure your Edge Router so it lets you access the `192.168.200.*/24` subnet (between the Edge Router and the TPLink router) from the `10.198.158.*` subnet (everything connected to the Edge Router). Details depend on what you've already set up ...

Comment: Will you care to explain step-by-step how to do that as an answer? Other than mode selection, everything is in the default configuration.

Comment: Following your direction, I followed the advice of 'odinb' from the thread https://community.ui.com/questions/NAT-rule-help-to-access-cable-modem-at-192-168-100-1/f731f0a1-d91a-464b-8638-cb05c99b3f22, and it worked. Simply speaking, I created an additional NAT rule in the Edgerouter that provides visibility to the TP-Link router. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you can also answer your own question, copy the specific information you used, and accept your own answer after some time. In this way, the next person with the same problem will have an answer. Comments are not guaranteed to be around.